# Is ( SU(2n), Sp(n)) a CW pair?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups, cw-complexes

I know that SO(n) can be given a CW complex structure, I wish to know if the pair  (SU(2n), Sp(n)) is a CW pair?

Comment: More generally any smooth manifold submanifold pair is a CW pair by a Morse theoretic argument. Much easier is that the inclusion is a cofibration, this only need tubular neighborhoods.